# Join with complex filters two spark datasets spark java

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have 2 Spark datasets as follows

> ```
> Dataset A :
>
> ColA | ColB | Col C   |   Col D      |  Col E
> 1       2       20       timestamp1     "text1"
>
> Dataset B :
>
> ColA | ColB | Col C  |    Col D   | Col E
> 1       2       20     timestamp1   "text2"
> ```

I want to join (on ColA and ColB) these two datasets with below condition

Condition can be

1. If ColC in Dataset A > ColC in Dataset B : in final output consider DatasetA
2. If ColC in Dataset A < ColC in Dataset B : in final output consider DatasetB
3. If ColC in Dataset A = ColC in Dataset B :

   1. If ColD in Dataset A > ColD in Dataset B : in final output consider DatasetA
   2. If ColD in Dataset A <= ColD in Dataset B : in final output consider DatasetB

> ```
> Output will be as follows (based on above condition)
> ColA | ColB | Col C  |    Col D   | Col E
> 1       2       20     timestamp1   "text2"
> ```
>
> Example 2 :
>
> ```
> Dataset A :
>
> ColA | ColB | Col C   |   Col D      |  Col E
> 1       2       20       timestamp1     "text1"
>
> Dataset B :
>
> ColA | ColB | Col C  |    Col D      | Col E
> 1       2       21      timestamp2     "text2"
>
> Output will be as follows (based on above condition)
> ColA | ColB | Col C  |    Col D   | Col E
> 1       2       21     timestamp2   "text2"
> ```

> Example 3 :
>
> ```
> Dataset A :
>
> ColA | ColB | Col C   |   Col D      |  Col E
> 1       2       22       timestamp1     "text1"
>
> Dataset B :
>
> ColA | ColB | Col C  |    Col D      | Col E
> 1       2       21      timestamp2     "text2"
>
> Output will be as follows (based on above condition)
> ColA | ColB | Col C  |    Col D   | Col E
> 1       2       21     timestamp1   "text1"
> ```

How do you achieve join as well as with the filtering conditions using Spark Java?Do we need to do reduce operation where we will compare the records and apply the condition and then do join ?

I tried out this sql directly where in I am able to get results where i give precedence to datasetB for ColC, ColD and ColE over datasetA
but I am not sure how to include the conditions of comparing colC and colD and then give precendence to datasetB or datasetA.

```scala
spark.sql(""" 
select  
  coalesce(datasetA.colA, datasetB.colA),  
  coalesce(datasetA.colB, datasetB.colB),   
  coalesce(datasetB.colC, datasetA.colC),  
  coalesce(datasetB.colD, datasetA.colD), 
  coalesce(datasetB.colE, datasetA.colE)  
from 
datasetA 
  full outer join
datasetB 
  on datasetB.colA=datasetA.colA 
  and datasetB.colB=datasetA.colB
""")
```

Comment: You can do an inner join and then a set of  SQL `case ... when ... then ... else` statements would work for you. Did you try anything? Please update your question as a [mcve]

Comment: @philantrovert : Thanks for the reply. Added what i tried.